# Передача делегата в неуправляемый код как указатель на функцию

Tags: c#, pinvoke, interop

Имеется неуправляемый метод, который принимает указатель на функцию `callback`.

Определенный прототип выглядит так:

```
typedef SDL_HitTestResult (SDLCALL *SDL_HitTest)
                          (SDL_Window *win, const SDL_Point *area, void *data);
```

Думаю определение делегата должно быть соответственно таким:

```
delegate HitTestResult HitTestDelegate(IntPtr windowPtr,
                                       IntPtr pointAreaPtr, IntPtr userData);
```

Но тут теперь возникает вопрос, нужно ли данный делегат помечать как указатель на неуправляемую функцию, т.е. ставить ему атрибут

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
delegate HitTestResult HitTestDelegate(IntPtr windowPtr,
                                       IntPtr pointAreaPtr, IntPtr userData);
```

Т.к. стоит `SDLCALL` определнный как `__cdecl`.

Answer (score 1):

Этот атрибут нужен не столько для указания того факта, что делегат нужно маршаллировать как указатель на функцию, сколько для указания соглашения о вызове. [Соглашение вызова по умолчанию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention?view=netframework-4.7.2) - stdcall, поэтому, если используется другое соглашение, естественно нужно это указать.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так?

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void MyFunctionDelegate(IntPtr frame);

[DllImport("my.dll")]
public extern static int MySetDataHandlerFunc(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]MyFunctionDelegate functionCallback);
```

1. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer?view=netframework-4.7.2
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969049/c-sharp-p-invoke-marshalling-structures-containing-function-pointers
3. http://www.xinterop.com/index.php/2013/04/13/introduction-to-c-pinvoke-interop-sdk/

Comment: В вопросе написано: `Но тут теперь возникает вопрос, нужно ли данный делегат помечать как указатель на неуправляемую функцию, т.е. ставить ему атрибут` т.к. там стоит соглашение о вызове, но никак не вопрос о том как это делать :)

Comment: Нет, кажется этого достаточно, есть декларация функции, есть делегат, делегат помечен, как в вашем случае, ничего более не требуется.

Comment: Если вам вам так кажется то вам стоит прочитать вот это: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5#cdecl

Comment: А чего там читать то? В вашем случае делегат должен быть помечен как `UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)`, я же в примере привел эту формулировку. Никаких иных телодвижений не требуется. И у вас в последнем примере указано то же самое :)

Comment: Я не могу посчитать ваш ответ как ответом на заданный вопрос, т.к. не вижу ничего кроме приведенного кода и ссылок на enSO, а самого главного, нужно ли это делать или нет, не вижу.

Comment: Это ваше право :) мне честно говоря это не сильно беспокоит, я в этом соцсоревновании активное участие не принимаю :) Что касается стоит или нет, вопрос аккуратности кода и вопрос будет ли работать без этого, попробуйте, но лучше соблюдать декларации в рамках рекомендаций языка.